# Java EE WebLogic and Spring with SSO

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, single-sign-on, waffle

I'm trying to get SSO working in my Spring app deployed on WebLogic 11. I'm using Waffle implementation for this.

I set:
    `entry-point-ref="negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint"`

and 
    `<custom-filter ref="waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />`

I've also added

```
<beans:bean id="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" class="waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl" />

<beans:bean id="negotiateSecurityFilterProvider" class="waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="basicSecurityFilterProvider" class="waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection" class="waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="negotiateSecurityFilterProvider" />
            <beans:ref bean="basicSecurityFilterProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint" class="waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="Provider" ref="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter" class="com.myapp.security.CustomNegotiateSecurityFilter">
    <beans:property name="Provider" ref="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection" />
</beans:bean>
```

My `CustomNegotiateSecurityFilter` is just a copy of standard Waffle class so it has no impact.

This configuration works fine when I use IP address to access app, but when hostname is used (with domain) I can't get SSO to work - 401 Unauthorised response.

Maybe somebody can advise the reason of such behaviour.

Comment: anybody? I really need to get this working, if you have any suggestion, possible reason, everything may be important.

Answer (score 0):

Since using the IP works, but using the name doesn't, this is most likely a problem with the SPN. You will need to use setspn to fix it. Start with the standard troubleshooting: https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Docs/Troubleshooting.md